# how do you add an attachement File in PeopleSoft?

Tags: peoplesoft

I am new on ERP PeopleSoft and I want to add a file attachment to my PeopleSoft page and I don't find solution, thanks

Comment: What application are you using? HRMS, campus solutions, finance, portal, etc?  I would ask an advanced user to identify an existing page where there is a file attachment control on an existing page.  I think that there is a file attachment tester page but I couldn't find it, maybe somewhere in integration broker.  I found a page that has a file upload control, at the navigation PeopleTools > Security > External Digital Certificates.  Add a new dummy entry to see the page.

Answer (score 0):

You first need somewhere to store it, so create a table and insert at least the subrecord `FILE_ATTDET_SBR`.

Now you just need some code to send the file over. You can start with
`AddAttachment` function.
`&Result = AddAttachment("record://YOUR_NEW_REC", &sysFName,"", &userFName, &InMaxSize);`

This [link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/F44947_01/pt858pbr3/eng/pt/tpcd/concept_UnderstandingtheFileAttachmentFunctions-ab7dac.html) here helps a lot: